# Do I need to peel butternut squash when roasting it in chunks?

Tags: roasting, squash

It seems like the peel is probably still inedible after roasting, but I'm not completely sure.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Peel is still inedible after roasting.
It's a *lot* easier to get off after cooking.
I usually cut squash in half, deseed, cook for an hour, then cut into pieces if I want to. You'll have to let it cool a bit before pulling the skin off the pieces.
Why even do that. I've served squash with skin for decades, and mo one ever complains. It lets people know that the stuff did not come out of a can.

Comment: It is incorrect that 'Peel is still inedible after roasting'. Probably the reason no one complains is that the skin is edible and even palatable to some people. See e.g. https://www.epicurious.com/expert-advice/peel-winter-squash-skins-article